# CMake: "ERROR: Package [...] build failed", error in m4 build() method

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake

I am trying to install a custom piece of software for my job. I downloaded the source, went inside the folder and typed `$ cmake ..`. After reading [AskUbuntu answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188643/port-gnulib-fseeko-c-to-your-platform-while-building-the-alexa-auto-sdk-on-ubunt), I deduced the problem comes from my m4 installation. I freshly installed m4, but nothing changes. When I run CMake, I have this:

```
$ cmake ..
-- Conan: Automatic detection of conan settings from cmake
-- Conan: Settings= -pr;default
-- Conan executing: conan install /home/user/app/conanfile.txt -pr default -g=cmake --build=outdated --no-imports

-- Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=9.4
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

asio/1.16.0: Package is up to date

[...]

  CC       freadahead.o
  CC       fseek.o
  CC       fseeko.o
  CC       mbrtowc.o
  CC       obstack.o
freadahead.c: In function 'freadahead':
freadahead.c:92:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
   92 |  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
      |   ^~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1910: freadahead.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
fseeko.c: In function 'rpl_fseeko':
fseeko.c:110:4: error: #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
  110 |   #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
      |    ^~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1910: fseeko.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/.conan/data/m4_installer/1.4.18/bincrafters/stable/build/44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830/source_subfolder/lib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1674: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/.conan/data/m4_installer/1.4.18/bincrafters/stable/build/44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830/source_subfolder/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1572: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/.conan/data/m4_installer/1.4.18/bincrafters/stable/build/44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830/source_subfolder'
make: *** [Makefile:1528: all] Error 2
m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable:
jsonformoderncpp/3.7.0: WARN: Recipe 'jsonformoderncpp/3.7.0' is deprecated in favor of 'nlohmann_json'. Please, consider changing your requirements.
m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Package binary is corrupted, removing: 44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830
m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: /home/user/.conan/data/m4_installer/1.4.18/bincrafters/stable/build/44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830
m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable: ERROR: Package '44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830' build failed
m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Build folder /home/user/.conan/data/m4_installer/1.4.18/bincrafters/stable/build/44fcf6b9a7fb86b2586303e3db40189d3b511830
ERROR: m4_installer/1.4.18@bincrafters/stable: Error in build() method, line 41
        env_build.make()
        ConanException: Error 2 while executing make -j8

CMake Error at cmake/modules/conan.cmake:371 (message):
  Conan install failed='1'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/conan.cmake:451 (conan_cmake_install)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (conan_cmake_run)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/app/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This is driving me crazy. I spent hours looking around, reinstalling m4 etc, but I still can't build this software.

The CMakeOutput.log file is very long, I put it [here](https://justpaste.it/c6boo).

If anyone has a solution or pointers, I'll take it! Thanks in advance. **I should add that I'm using WSL2 on Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20**.

Comment: It sounds like the error is related to the `conan` build system's own `m4_installer`, rather than anything related to your system's native m4 package

Comment: @steeldriver interesting, thank you! So, should I reinstall or update Conan maybe?

Comment: Back at work, I upgraded Conan but still get the same errors. I have no idea what to do, this is frustrating!

Comment: Okay I go it to work! I contacted the people who developed the app I was trying to install. They told me to update the requirements in CMakeLists.txt : `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`, and conanfile.txt: `[requires]
fmt/7.1.0
nlohmann_json/3.9.1
libpcap/1.10.1`

Comment: @C.Crt Good to hear you got it working.  Please post what you did as an *answer* rather than a comment.  You can then self-accept the answer (probably after a short-delay).  This will allow others to find your answer when they search the relevant terms -- Comments aren't search-indexed.  It will also prevent the question from being "bumped" later by the Community Bot.  Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trouble I got it to work. I contacted the people who developed the app I was trying to install. They told me to update the requirements in `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

and `conanfile.txt` :

```
[requires] fmt/7.1.0 
nlohmann_json/3.9.1 
libpcap/1.10.1
```